# What's this called?

Tags: meaning, grammar, vocabulary, spoken-english, names

So, I skipped my morning breakfast and went off to write an exam.  I came back home at the time of lunch, but I slept, without eating. I had my first meal of the day at around 5PM. So what would this be called?

Breakfast, Lunch, Snack or anything else?

Comment: ;)  I will say dinner..    :D

Answer (score 1):

The word that people choose to describe a meal is usually based on **the time of the day** not, the number of the meal. Because of that, I would say that **dinner** is the best word to describe the meal.

- `Breakfast` is almost exclusively used to describe a meal in the morning. Even though its usually the first main meal of the day, not everyone eats their first meal in the morning.
- `Lunch` refers to a meal in the middle of the day.
- `Snack` refers to a small meal. This word could be appropriate, but if this meal is their only meal of the entire day, the word `snack` probably wouldn't make sense.